# openCV error:"Sizes of input arguments do not match" while trying to detect objects using HoG features and SVM

Tags: opencv, image-processing, svm, object-detection

I am working on object detection using HoG Features and SVM. I am calculating HoG features for 64X128 images using the code in [this (Integral Histogram for fast Calculation of HOG Features)](http://smsoftdev-solutions.blogspot.in/2009/08/integral-histogram-for-fast-calculation.html)    and [this (Calculation of Hog Features)](http://smsoftdev-solutions.blogspot.in/2009/10/object-detection-using-opencv-ii.html) for both positive(pos.xml) and Negative(neg.xml) images.  I am training the SVM with the pos.xml and neg.xml . When I try to detect using the xml file saved using SVM training , it gives me following error. (image size used for detection is 64X128)

> OpenCV Error: Sizes of input arguments do not match (The sample size
>   is differen t from what has been used for training) in
>   cvPreparePredictData, file .......
>   .\opencv\modules\ml\src\inner_functions.cpp, line 1114

My code for detecting images.

```
    Mat img= imread("path\\a91.jpg"); // 64X128 pixels
    CvSVM svm;
    svm.load("svm1.xml");
    Mat example;
    cvtColor(img,example,CV_RGB2GRAY);
    example = example.reshape(0,1);
    //cout  <<type2str(example.type()) <<endl;



    example.convertTo(example, CV_32FC1);

    //cout  <<type2str(example.type()) <<endl;
    cout<<svm.predict(example)<<endl;
```

SVM training code :

```
void trainSVM(CvMat* pos_mat, CvMat* neg_mat, char *savexml, char *pos_file = NULL, char *neg_file = NULL) 
{


    /* Read the feature vectors for positive samples */
    if (pos_file != NULL) 
        {
        printf("positive loading...\n");
        pos_mat = (CvMat*) cvLoad(pos_file);
        printf("positive loaded\n");
    }

    /* Read the feature vectors for negative samples */
    if (neg_file != NULL)
    {
        neg_mat = (CvMat*) cvLoad(neg_file);
        printf("negative loaded\n");
    }

    int n_positive, n_negative;
    n_positive = pos_mat->rows;
    n_negative = neg_mat->rows; 
    int feature_vector_length = pos_mat->cols;
    int total_samples;
    total_samples = n_positive + n_negative;

    CvMat* trainData = cvCreateMat(total_samples,feature_vector_length, CV_32FC1);

    CvMat* trainClasses = cvCreateMat(total_samples,1, CV_32FC1 );

    CvMat trainData1, trainData2, trainClasses1,
    trainClasses2;

    printf("Number of positive Samples : %d\n",pos_mat->rows);

    /*Copy the positive feature vectors to training
    data*/

    cvGetRows(trainData, &trainData1, 0, n_positive);
    cvCopy(pos_mat, &trainData1);
    cvReleaseMat(&pos_mat);

    /*Copy the negative feature vectors to training
    data*/

    cvGetRows(trainData, &trainData2, n_positive,total_samples);

    cvCopy(neg_mat, &trainData2);
    cvReleaseMat(&neg_mat);

    printf("Number of negative Samples : %d\n",trainData2.rows);

    /*Form the training classes for positive and
    negative samples. Positive samples belong to class
    1 and negative samples belong to class 2 */

    cvGetRows(trainClasses, &trainClasses1, 0, n_positive);
    cvSet(&trainClasses1, cvScalar(1));

    cvGetRows(trainClasses, &trainClasses2, n_positive, total_samples);

    cvSet(&trainClasses2, cvScalar(2));


    /* Train a linear support vector machine to learn from
    the training data. The parameters may played and
    experimented with to see their effects*/

    CvSVM svm(trainData, trainClasses, 0, 0, CvSVMParams(CvSVM::C_SVC, CvSVM::LINEAR, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, cvTermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_EPS,0, 0.01)));

    printf("SVM Training Complete!!\n");

    /*Save the learnt model*/

    if (savexml != NULL) {
        svm.save(savexml);
    }
    cvReleaseMat(&trainClasses);
    cvReleaseMat(&trainData);

}
```

Please help me with this. I am stuck here. Thank you.

Comment: You have to extract the HOG features from the test image as well. You cannot give the image itself to SVM (well you can, but that's a different story altogether..)